# Ionic Builed Project Failed : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm new with ionic frameworks. i'm try to to build android with command `sudo build --release android` and get error as below

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
  The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0, androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.core:core:1.0.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/Muhamadkhairuldin/Google Drive/SifuApps/Apps/usahaone5/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b /Users/Muhamadkhairuldin/Google Drive/SifuApps/Apps/usahaone5/platforms/android/build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.
```

can anybody help me how to solve this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you fixed this?